# Are there any .NET Graphics Calculate Libraries?

Tags: .net, math, graphics, numerical

I want to find a Calculate Library not a Drawing Library to help me do some graphics calulation like Bezier's length, point on Beziers or other metadata.

Is there any library like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://www.rightedgesystems.com/forums/Topic6407-18-1.aspx) forum discussion, and take a look at [Math.NET](http://mathnet.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much,It's very helpful.

also thanks ars,alglib is a good lib,too.

Answer (score 1):

ALGLIB may have what you need and is open source:

- http://www.alglib.net/

IMSL is a well regarded commercial library which implements many numerical algorithms:

- http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/cSharp/overview.php

Comment: Thank you,It's very useful infomation.